# React, Data-Attributes, and Inconsistent Results

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, custom-data-attribute

VIDEO DEMONSTRATION OF THE ISSUE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjY6Y2DIEZI

I'm trying to create a "star"/"like" button and have run into a perplexing issue. Below is my code:

```
    <IconButton
      className="starsButton"
      data-targetpost={props.post._id}
      onClick={starClickHandler}
    >
      {starsToggle ? <StarIcon /> : <StarBorderIcon />}
      {props.post.stars.length}
    </IconButton>
```

On the starClickHandler, right now I just have a console.log to show for me the targetpost value of the given button clicked, shown below.

```
function starClickHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.target.dataset.targetpost);
  setStarsToggle((prev) => !prev);
}
```

I have been receiving inexplicably inconsistent results from this - I have a list of posts and as I go through the posts, some will console log the desired result of the target post being "starred" and some will console.log "undefined"". Whats more confusing is that the value will inexplicably change from undefined to the desired result, or vice versa, with no inputs other than clicking the button a few times. Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: The function that is creating my post components (where the button resides) is below.

```
export default function Home(props) {
  const postFeed = props.postFeed.map((x) => {
    return <Post post={x} key={x._id}></Post>;
  });

  async function commentSubmitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target);
  }

  return <div>{postFeed}</div>;
}
```

The function that gets data to populate the posts is here:

```
  async function getUserData() {
let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/", {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "cors",
  headers: { Authorization: authToken, Origin: "localhost:8080" },
});
if (response.status === 200) {
  let userData = await response.json();
  setLoggedInUser({
    userID: userData._doc._id,
    username: userData._doc.username,
  });
  // console.log(userData);
  updatePostFeed(userData._doc.posts);
} else {
  console.log("You are not logged in.");
}}
```

The full code for the post component is here:

```
    export default function Post(props) {
  const userInfo = React.useContext(UserContext);

  const [commentsToggle, setCommentsToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [starsToggle, setStarsToggle] = React.useState(false);

  function starClickHandler(event) {
    setStarsToggle((prev) => !prev);
    console.log(event.target.dataset.targetpost);
  }

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <p className="postAuthor">
        <b>{props.post.author.username}</b> posted:
      </p>
      <p className="postContent">{props.post.content}</p>
      <p>{props.post.formatted_date}</p>
      <span className="postButtonContainer">
        <IconButton
          className="starsButton"
          data-targetpost={props.post._id}
          onClick={starClickHandler}
        >
          {starsToggle ? <StarIcon /> : <StarBorderIcon />}
          {props.post.stars.length}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          className="commentsButton"
          onClick={() => {
            setCommentsToggle((prev) => !prev);
          }}
        >
          {commentsToggle ? <ChatBubbleIcon /> : <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon />}
          {props.post.comments.length}
        </IconButton>
      </span>
      <hr></hr>
      {commentsToggle ? (
        <div>
          <CommentList comments={props.post.comments}></CommentList>
          <NewCommentInput targetPostURL={props.post.url}></NewCommentInput>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you show more amount of code ?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal I just did.

Comment: I just tried to set the button ID to be the target-post-id, and now when I try to console.log that I sometimes get "empty string", even though I can see in the DOM tree that the element DOES have an ID. And just like the behaviour when I was storing the value in a data-attribute, it will somrtimes show empty string and then seemingly at random it will show the actual value, even though nothing has changed.

Comment: I just added a video demonstration of the issue to the post.